# Tooltip control

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using `bootstrap` library.

I want to use `tooltip` for the slider I designed.

To use the `tooltip` in the `slider`, I need to create special conditions.

**In summary:**

I want the `tooltip` not to be displayed whenever the user `hovers` over one of the slides, and the `tooltip` of only the slide whose `z-index` is equal to `1` should be displayed.

Please help me to complete the code of the script I wrote.

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});


        $("li").each(function () {
            if ($(this).css("z-index") == 1) {
                $("div.tooltip").css("display", "block");
            } else {
                $("div.tooltip").css("display", "none");
            }
        });

        $("li").each(function () {
            if ($(this).css("z-index") == 0) {
                $("div.tooltip").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
```

```css
ul.body-slider {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

.body-slider li.slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.body-slider li.slide a {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #eb00ff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.body-slider li.num-1 a,
.body-slider li.num-3 a {
    background: #51ff00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}


.body-slider li.num-1 {
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.body-slider li.num-3 {
    top: 25px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.body-slider li.num-2 {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <section>

        <div class="main-slider">

            <ul class="body-slider">
                <li class="slide num-1">
                    <a href="#"
                        title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit mollitia voluptatem saepe odio incidunt, earum fuga ea placeat et laudantium!"
                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">slide #1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="slide num-2">
                    <a href="#"
                        title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit mollitia voluptatem saepe odio incidunt, earum fuga ea placeat et laudantium!"
                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">slide #2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="slide num-3">
                    <a href="#"
                        title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit mollitia voluptatem saepe odio incidunt, earum fuga ea placeat et laudantium!"
                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">slide #3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>


    </section>
```

Comment: Hello. I edited my question and put all the code I wrote so far.

Comment: please hit the accept button (green check mark) if it worked for your

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, I should mention that Jquery is not recommended anymore and it's about to extinction if it hasn't yet. so it would be better if you update your project to BootStrap v5 and use pure js code instead of jquery. However I think this is the code you are looking for :

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $("ul").children('li').each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).css("z-index") == 1) {
            $($(this).children()[0]).tooltip('enable')
        } else {
            $($(this).children()[0]).tooltip('disable')
        }
    });
});
```

Do not change your HTML and CSS code, just replace this code with your script

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your time. I used your code in my slider. Your code works correctly, but I want the tooltip to remain fixed and not show or hide the tooltip when hovering over the slide. In short, the hover feature should be removed and the tooltip should remain fixed for this slide.

Comment: @Hossein so use 'show' instead of 'enable'

Comment: I tried this. But there is still the hover problem. I want the hover property to be disabled.

Comment: By changing **'enable'** to **'show'**, I got what I wanted, but by **hovering** over the slide, the **tooltip** is hidden, and I don't know how to fix this problem. I just want the piece of code that removes the **hover** feature on the desired slide.

Comment: what do you mean to disable the hover feature?

Comment: Hello. I apologize for the late reply. I have created a new question related to this topic so that you can easily understand what I mean by hovering, and I would be happy if you would take a look at this question:[Tooltip control (remain stable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030795/tooltip-control-remain-stable)